# Tours of Abandoned stations of New York's Subway

Tags: usa, public-transport, new-york-city

I have found a list on [NYCSubway.org](http://www.nycsubway.org) of abandoned stations of the New York's Subway.

Some of them look pretty amazing like the closed [City Hall Station](http://www.nycsubway.org/wiki/Station%3a_City_Hall_%28IRT_East_Side_Line%29).

I just wonder if there are tours available of these stations?  I am fairly happy to do it on my own but I'd prefer at least an initial walkthrough with someone who knows their way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Brooklyn-based [New York Transit Museum](http://www.mta.info/mta/museum/) conducts [regular tours of the City Hall Station](http://www.mta.info/mta/museum/programs.htm#offsite-tours); however, the event is restricted to [museum members](http://web.mta.info/mta/museum/#membership) at the $40 level and above. Tickets are currently $90 each, and require a copy of a government-issued ID and the signing of a release. The Museum conducts occasional tours of other facilities (e.g. the [Williamsburg Bridge Railway Terminal](http://www.columbia.edu/~brennan/abandoned/willb.html) is currently on the calendar), and is itself situated in the disused Court Street station.

As New York's subway system is quite old and extensive, there are many abandoned tunnels and stations. It is possible to see some of them as trains currently in service [pass through them](http://untappedcities.com/2013/08/13/7-nyc-abandoned-subway-stations-city-hall-18th-street-worth-myrtle/)— indeed, it is well-known that riding the [6 train](http://www.mta.info/nyct/service/sixline.htm) to the end of the line (Brooklyn Bridge) will take you through the City Hall Station. There is a community of "urban spelunkers" who [sneak into them](http://ltvsquad.com/subways/), and do [more dramatic things in them](http://gothamist.com/2013/06/24/photos_illegal_party_in_an_abandone.php); however, doing so is quite illegal and can be quite dangerous, and I would never recommend it as a tourist activity.